# Is there a way to navigate and filter only opened files in sublime text?

Tags: sublimetext3, keyboard-shortcuts, text-editor

Is there a keyboard shortcut or an extension to navigate and filter only opened files in sublime text such like (Ctrl+P) but the menu only contains opened files ?

Answer (score 0):

Find Menu -> Replace (Cmd + Shift + F in Mac/ Ctrl + Shift + F in windows)

[image]

Comment: I didn't mean searching for words , what I meant is similar to (Ctrl+P) but the menu contains only opened files.